# How can I hide an element off the edge of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I've got a div that I want to position partially off-screen like so:

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    right: -50px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

But this increases the size of the page, allowing it to be scrolled to the right. Is there any way to keep half of this div hidden and prevent scrolling to view it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, just create an enclosing div with `overflow: hidden`, like this:

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Uj3eQ/

Comment: add position:relative/fixed/absolute; to the .outer

Comment: Note: the code as given will result in the inner content not being shown on screen. You need to position the outer div within your document as you want and then the inner `position: absolute` will be relative to the outer div.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `overflow:hidden` to the css. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Just insert this div inside another div with `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 3):

You could add a media query to avoid scrolling at a certain point. So basically take the width of your main container and create a min-width media-query using that.

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    body {
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

Should work for modern browsers.

Comment: In this case you should use max-width instead of min-width. You want the browser to clip the overflow when the browser in less than or equal to 960px (which is max-width), otherwise the scrollbar is not present in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use `margin-left: 100%;`

And if you wanted to play with the positioning a bit, you can do something like `margin-left: calc(100% + 10px);`

And another alternate way is to do `float: right;` and then play around with `margin-right -50px;` where 50px is the width of the hidden div. You could even have a neat transition if you animate the `margin-right` if you were making a menu.

Comment: It's a bad idea to animate layout-related properties due to performance limitations. It's better to use the `transform: translateX()` for such things.

Comment: @SlavaFominII No, there's nothing wrong with animating margins. Even on mobile. Like with any animations, it depends a lot on how you go about it. Here is a fiddle with both methods side-by-side, besides some small easing differences, it's almost identical. You can even open up CPU profile in dev tools and see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/rock6zLq/

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but answering for new visitors. This should do it:

```
.offscreen {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    transform: translateX(50px);
 }
```

---

`position: fixed` is placing the element relative to the viewport (browser window). Think of `fixed` as being the same as `absolute`, *except* it's the relative to the viewport, ignoring all other divs.

Then we place the element on the top right corner with `top: 0` and `right: 0`

We have this:

```
          ______________
         |     [Element]|
         |              |
         |              |
         |  (Viewport)  | 
         |              |
         |              |
         |______________|
```

Then we move the element to the right by 50px with `transform: translateX(50px)`:

```
          ______________
         |          [Ele|ment]
         |              |
         |              |
         |  (Viewport)  | 
         |              |
         |              |
         |______________|
```

But seeing that the element has a width of 100px and you're moving by 50px, which is **half** of the width, then it's better to do it like this instead: `transform: translateX(50%)`

The advantage of using percentages is that even if you later change the width to 120px for example, you won't have to manually the change from `translateX(50px)` to `translateX(60px)`. By using percentage the math is done for you.

*Note: This is not affected by zooming in/out and also does not cause overflow (scrolling).*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation where I needed an absolutely placed element to be positioned partially to the right of the main content header. If the browser was wide enough to show it, I did NOT want to clip it (overflow: hidden;) but I also did not want to make the scrollbar appear if the browser was not wide enough.

Here is the code I used:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1275px) {
  #header {
     overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scroll is may be you have placed relative position property to the containing div and it result the required div to go off the right by -50 but as relative to the main containing div not the browser viewable area.. if its parent div just inside the body tag or the parent div does not include any position property your code should work.. and again you can apply overflow:hidden property to wrapper div to hideout the unnecessary part