# stop viewport resizing when an element is part off the p5.js canvas

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, processing, p5.js

I'm building a visual interaction using p5.js (p5js.org), including p5.dom.js so that I can do some html stuff within it.

I'm having trouble stopping an html image element increasing the size of the viewport when it moves off of the p5.js canvas (which is also an element.

I have tried adapting a solution suggested here [CSS- hide element off the right of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746649/css-hide-element-off-the-right-of-the-screen) involving placing an element within another element which has styling set to `overflow:hidden` and `position:relative` to no avail –the image just disappears.

Although commenting/uncommenting the  `pictureContainer.style("position", "relative");` in the code below does actually hide/show the image, which makes me wonder if it's some kind of conflict between p5js and html styling?!

I have alternatively tried setting up the parent container in the index.html and doing `var x = select("parent div #id in index.html"); picture.parent(x);` in my p5 script but I get the same result as above.

FYI, I am using `createImg()` from p5.dom.js and then using .style to position the image etc. as the project is running in a phonegap shell and I have had issues with the p5.js method `loadImage()` on iOS.

Here's my problem code:

```js
//time keeping
var timeKeeper;

//picture container
var pictureContainer;
//picture
var pictureLoaded;
var picture;

//display picture bool
var pictureDisplay;

//p5 canvas
var canvas;

function setup() {
  
  //create the p5 canvas element
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  // canvas.style("zIndex", "-1") //changing this doesn't seem to help
  
  //container to hold picture and supposedly prevent it affecting the viewport
  pictureContainer = createDiv("test");
  pictureContainer.style("overflow", "hidden");
  pictureContainer.style("position", "relative");
  // pictureContainer.position(0,0); //this doesn't do anything differently to the line above except move the container to top left of window
  pictureContainer.style("width", "0");
  pictureContainer.style("zIndex", "999");
 
  //create image
  picture = createImg("http://images.clipartpanda.com/foam-clipart-1334260620683400173foam_finger.svg", "fingerTransparent")
  //make picture the child of pictureContainer
  picture.parent(pictureContainer); //comment this and you'll see the picture appear, resizing the viewport every time it does.
  
  //position(x,y) sets the image position styling to position:absolute, left:x, top:y -- as such:http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/position
  picture.position(windowWidth/2,windowHeight/2); 
  //for displaying/hiding the picture  
  pictureDisplay = false;
  timeKeeper = 0;

}


function draw() {


  canvas.background(100, 100, 100);

  //display/show picture
  if(millis()>timeKeeper+1000){
    timeKeeper=millis();
    if(pictureDisplay){
      picture.style("display","initial"); 
      pictureDisplay=false;
    }
    else{
      picture.style("display","none"); 
      pictureDisplay=true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>


    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>        

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="exampleCode.js" ></script>
                
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `div` as a container for your canvas and the picture element.
Set the styles for this container to `style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"`

In the setup function parent the canvas and the created image to this container.

Example:

```js
//time keeping
var timeKeeper;

//picture container
var pictureContainer;
//picture
var pictureLoaded;
var picture;

//display picture bool
var pictureDisplay;

//p5 canvas
var canvas;

function setup() {
  
  //create the p5 canvas element
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  //parent the canvas to the div container defined in the html
  canvas.parent("sketch-holder");
  
  //create image
  picture = createImg("http://images.clipartpanda.com/foam-clipart-1334260620683400173foam_finger.svg", "fingerTransparent")
  //parent the picture to the same container 
  picture.parent("sketch-holder");
  
  //position(x,y) sets the image position styling to position:absolute, left:x, top:y -- as such:http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/position
  picture.position(windowWidth/2,windowHeight/2); 
  //for displaying/hiding the picture  
  pictureDisplay = false;
  timeKeeper = 0;

}


function draw() {

  canvas.background(100, 100, 100);

  //display/show picture
  if(millis()>timeKeeper+1000){
    timeKeeper=millis();
    if(pictureDisplay){
      picture.style("display","initial"); 
      pictureDisplay=false;
    }
    else{
      picture.style("display","none"); 
      pictureDisplay=true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
 <html>
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<title>Tester</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
<script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
 }
 canvas {
  display: block;
  
 }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="sketch-holder" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this! it works great. although I'm still getting a nominal slider appearing for the vertical axis, though I don't think this isn't anything to do with the image overflow problem as I have seen it on other p5js sketches.

Comment: it's the default margin on the body I guess. Try `<body style="margin: 0">` inside the html.

Comment: I already tried that and it makes no difference. Also <body style="padding: 0">. Both of these are useful for getting rid of any whitespace around the edge. However applying <body style="overflow: hidden"> got rid of the scrollbar, although I'm not sure I feel comfortable applying it in this way as there may be other html elements layered on top of the p5 sketch.

Comment: Actually the canvas needs a `display: block;`style as well. I updated the script in the answer. The new styles are inside the style tag.